# neo4j circumvent aggregation over union

Tags: neo4j, cypher

To practice a bit with Cypher I made up a simple example with students being friends with other students attending certain classes.

Now I would like to understand how classes contribute in making friends from different towns, so, I would need to compute how many students from different towns meet because of friendship or because they attend the same class.

Normally I would aggregate over the result of the following union by counting the occurrences of each pair (p1.town, p2.town). 
    
    `MATCH (p1: Person) -[:FRIEND_OF]-> (p2: Person)
    WHERE p1.id <> p2.id
    AND p1.town <> p2.town
    RETURN p1.town, p2.town
    UNION ALL
    MATCH (q1: Person) <-[:COMPOSED_BY]- (:SchoolClass) -[:COMPOSED_BY]-> (q2: Person)
    WHERE q1.id <> q2.id
    AND q1.town <> q2.town
    RETURN p1.town, p2.town`

But, unfortunately, aggregating over a union is a feature that Neo4J (and Cypher) does not feature [yet](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/2725).

Does anybody have any idea how to rewrite the query?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand exactly what you are after, but in general you can sometimes avoid `UNION` by using `WITH` to divide your query. Just make sure to collect all the results from the first subquery so that there is only one result item by the time the second subquery begins (or the second subquery will be run once for each result item).

```
MATCH (p1:Person)-[:FRIEND_OF]->(p2:Person)
WHERE p1.id <> p2.id                        // Necessary? Are your :Persons friends with themselves?
AND p1.town <> p2.town
WITH COLLECT([p1.town, p2.town]) as friendTownPairs
MATCH (q1:Person)<-[:COMPOSED_BY]-(:SchoolClass)-[:COMPOSED_BY]->(q2:Person)
WHERE q1.id <> q2.id                        // Again, probably not necessary, unless a :SchoolClass can have two :COMPOSED_BY relationships to the same :Person
AND q1.town <> q2.town
RETURN COLLECT([p1.town, p2.town]) as classmateTownPairs
```

Like I said, I'm not sure exactly what computation you want to make on the results. If you were able to aggregate on the union, what would it look like? It looks like you want to get the person.town pairs for any two persons who either are friends or belong to the same school class (the union of those two queries), in which case you could do something like

```
MATCH (p:Person), (q:Person)
WHERE p-[:FRIEND_OF]->q OR p<-[:COMPOSED_BY]-(:SchoolClass)-[:COMPOSED_BY]->(q)
RETURN p.town, q.town
```

I hope I'm not misunderstanding completely.

Comment: I'm sorry, probably my question wasn't so clear: I wanted to count te pairs of people from different towns who interact, so, after the two unions I wanted to write something like:
`RETURN town1, town2, count(*)`.

Your last listing solves my problem! Many thanks!